# turn chained useFetch queries into useLazyFetch ones in NuxtJS3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm coming back to frontend web development and i thought it would be funny to try using NuxtJS 3 as my first framework.

I'm a backend dev (PHP, GoLang, C#) just trying to learn something new so my project doesn't need to be perfect but i'm hiting a wall trying to transform something that is working with useFetch (and load the whole content but take a long time to do it) toward using useLazyFetch (so the page load quickly and the content fills up over time).

So here's the TS part of my component :

```
<script setup>
        const props = defineProps([
            'Id'
        ])
        
        const route = useRoute();
        
        let fetchedPost = {
            Id: "",
            SharedId: "",
            OwnerUid: "",
            Content: "",
            ReplyTo: "",
            QuoteTo: "",
            DatePost: "",
            DateEdit: "",
            DateDeleted: "",
        };
        
        let finalPost = ref({
            Id: "",
            UserName: "",
            Name: "",
            Content: "",
            DatePost: "",
            SharedId: "",
            ReplyTo: "",
            QuoteTo: "",
            ReactionsCount: "",
            ShareQuotedCount: "",
            ResponseCount: "",
        })
        
        const { data: dataPost, pending } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bp/post/${props.Id}`);
        if (dataPost.value) {
            fetchedPost = dataPost?.value?.Data.post;
            finalPost.value.Id = fetchedPost.Id;
            finalPost.value.Content = fetchedPost.Content;
            finalPost.value.DatePost = fetchedPost.DatePost;
            finalPost.value.SharedId = fetchedPost.SharedId;
            finalPost.value.ReplyTo = fetchedPost.ReplyTo;
            finalPost.value.QuoteTo = fetchedPost.QuoteTo;
            const { data: dataUser } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bp/user/i/${fetchedPost.OwnerUid}`);
            if (dataUser.value) {
                let fetchedUser = dataUser?.value?.Data.user
                finalPost.value.UserName = fetchedUser.Username;
                finalPost.value.Name = fetchedUser.Name;
            }
            const { data: countRepliesData } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bp/post/${props.Id}/replies/count`);
            if (countRepliesData.value) {
                finalPost.value.ResponseCount = countRepliesData?.value?.Data.count;
            }
            const { data: countSharesQuotesData } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bp/post/${props.Id}/shares/count`);
            if (countSharesQuotesData.value) {
                finalPost.value.ShareQuotedCount = countSharesQuotesData?.value?.Data.count;
            }
            const { data: countReactData } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bp/post/${props.Id}/reactions/count`);
            if (countReactData.value) {
                finalPost.value.ReactionsCount = countReactData?.value?.Data.count;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I attempted to replace the useFetch with useLazyFetch, and the stupid part is that **it works when I just replace the first one (calling for data: dataPost), save, Nuxt hot-reload the code, i can see my post filling up with all the datas**, but when i refresh the page, all my datas are gone, and i can't figure out why.

Note that the project is configured as ssr:false in the nuxt config file.

I guess i did something wrong, but since i have a pretty low experience in frontend development in general and nuxt in particular, i guess i may have missed something stupid.
So please, enlighten me.
(Also, don't hesitate to give me advice on a better way to chain my fetch calls, i am here to learn).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of a better idea for chained `useFetch`. I'll try to make it simpler.

First, in order to make the `useLazyFetch` to work, you need to disable the `ssr` on the entire app or on a specific route. Here's how you do it.

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
// Disable SSR on your entire app
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false
})
```

To disable `ssr` on a specific page, add this on the `config` file.

```js
// Disable SSR on a specific route
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    'you-specified-route': { ssr: false }
  }
})
```

See Rendering Nuxt rendering modes [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering)

Once that is setup, you should be able to use the `useLazyFetch` composable in your pages.

Here is my example of chaining of fetching data and it works

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
interface UserData {
    name: string
    email: string
    phone: number
}
const finalData = ref<UserData | null>(null)
const { data: first, pending } = await useLazyFetch('/api/first-api')

// Watch any changes on the 'first' data
watch(first, async (newValue, oldValue) => {
    // The oldValue will be null and the newValue will store the data from the API
    // console.log(oldValue)
    if (newValue) {
        const { data: second } = await useFetch('/api/second-api')
        finalData.value = second.value
    }
})

// This will display if loading state of the API
watch(pending, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log('Is loading', oldValue)
    console.log('Is loading', newValue)
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="pending">
            loading...
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ finalData }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]
[image]

Tested and it works. Hope that helps you.

Comment: oh nice!
i had to adapt it a little bit of course but now it works perfectly. i was sure that had something to do with the watch function but i couldn't figurate how to use it properly (i missed the use the the async in the call of it).
that's amazing, thank you very much i was going mad with that thing!

Answer (score -1):

The issues you are experiencing are due to server side rendering on the initial visit of the page. Reloading (via F5) also is treated as a initial page visit. Navigation on the page or hot-reload on the other hand are happening on the client side. This is why useLazyFetch works after hot-reloading in your case but not in conjunction with SSR.

Like stated in the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#client-only-fetching) I think you can achieve what you want by using the following approach which works lazy but runs on the client side only:

```
const { data: countRepliesData } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/bp/post/${props.Id}/replies/count`, {
  lazy: true,
  server: false
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, useLazyFetch is basically useFetch with the lazy parameter already at true.
And i forgot to mentionned but my project is configured as ```ssr : false``` so i guess the server: false is already here too. i've tested what you posted anyway and it and it doesn't work :/.